# std::string s1 {"Modern C++", 3} vs std::string s1 {str, 3}

Tags: c++, string, c++17

The output of the following code confuses me:

```
const std::string str = "Modern C++";

std::string s1 {"Modern C++", 3};
std::string s2 {str, 3};

std::cout << "S1: " << s1 << "\n";
std::cout << "S2: " << s2 << "\n";
```

> output:

```
> S1: Mod
> S2: ern C++
```

Can anyone explain this result?

Comment: S1 and S2 should be the same unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you read [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) on `std::string` constructors? `"Modern C++"` is not an `std::string` but a character array (that's automatically converted to a char pointer), and there's a different constructor for those.

Comment: Sure.  The reference would tell you that.  And I'm sure there's some amazingly clever reason these don't do the same thing, which the C++ library committee would prove to me using impeccable logic and reasoning.  And yet this is just one more reason - albeit small - that the C++ standard library remains unintuitive, even frustrating, to use.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat nevertheless, the result should be the same, thanks anyway.

Comment: Yep, it probably should.

Comment: The "amazingly clever reason" is that std::string was initially designed decades ago, so in hindsight some of its constructors and functions don't fit with what we would consider a modern intuitive interface

Comment: @M.M.: That, plus the fact that C-style strings were designed even longer ago, and `std::string` had to work with their conventions. That said, probably should have stuck with the same, C-style string semantics for both, instead of having a position be an effective start point for `std::string`, and an effective end point for `char *`, so your point still stands, just pointing out that compatibility constraints in this realm predate even `std::string`.

Comment: This is really a beautifully perfect example of why some might claim that C++ "sucks".

Comment: @M.M Consistency and logic are hardly recent inventions

Comment: TBH, I think the real issue is that each class has one constructor name - the class name. You can't have different constructors for the same class with different names, and can only have multiple constructors at all because of overloading. Different overloads with the same name doing different things is smelly, but that's what we're stuck with for constructors. Except that what you should probably do is move-construct from a named function that returns the value you want - don't use all the confusing constructors at all, they're IMO obsolete relics from an age before move semantics.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

```
std::string s1 {"Modern C++", 3};
```

Uses the following constructor:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
          size_type count,
          const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So takes 3 chars to get `Mod`.

```
std::string s2 {str, 3};
```

will use the following constructor:

```
basic_string( const basic_string& other,
          size_type pos,
          const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So taking the string from position 3 onwards giving : `ern C++`.

Comment: Thank you. the first one is `size_type count` and the second is `size_type pos`.

Comment: One has to ask why they'd ever add two constructors with such differing behavior. Its like it was cobbled together with no thought at all.

Comment: @Polygnome: "Cobbled together with no thought at all" basically describes the whole of `std::string`. It also accounts for the mix of index-based and iterator-based methods -- string was developed independently of the STL, then retroactively augmented to match -- and in general has too many "convenience methods. I always like [GOTW #84: Monoliths Unstrung](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) which dives into a minimal string API supplemented by free functions.

Comment: Is there even a use case for this substring constructor that wouldn't be served by the `substr` method?

Answer (score 35):

One is calling `string(char const*, count)`, the other `string(string const&, pos)`.

One gets the first 3 characters from a buffer, the other all the characters after the 3rd one.

This is because C++ has raw character buffers and std strings.  `"this is not a std::string"`.  `"this is a std string"s`, `std::string so_is="this";`.

`std::string` is more than 30 years old, and it was added to the C++ language without sufficient care (unlike the STL, which went through more iterations before being added).

Its interface is honestly too rich, and you can run into stuff like this; multiple overloads that lead to confusing results.

Answer (score 7):

> Can anyone explain to me why is that?

That is due to `std::string` having constructors which it really shouldn't (@ORR [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534356/1593077) the details). And it shouldn't have these constructors because:

1. Their effect is easily achievable using [named constructor idioms](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom) /  `std::string` methods and existing constructors - at no extra cost (in C++11 at least), and
2. It is not obvious and trivial to understand how the constructor arguments are used from just looking at the constructor invocation.

This is not the only case in the standard library with such undersirable (IMHO) constructors; [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is (in)famous for [too much constructor variety](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and confusing/misleading constructor semantics.

**Life lessons:**

- Skimp on constructors; not every commonly-used bunch of values used to construct an object of your class deserve their own constructor;
- instead, use [named constructor idioms](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom).
- Have your code reviewer or some other less-biased party read an invocation of your constructors, to gauge whether the meaning of each one is obvious enough.

Answer (score 3):

Incase you want to get the same output like

*Mod* for s1

*Mod* for s2

You can use a char pointer for str e.g

```
char * str = "Modern C++";

std::string s1 {"Modern C++", 3};
std::string s2 {str, 3};

std::cout << "S1: " << s1 << "\n";
std::cout << "S2: " << s2 << "\n";
```

The output

```
 Mod

 Mod
```

Comment: In order for this to work,the first line should be : 
char str[] = "Modern C++";
or
char str[] {"Modern C++"};

Comment: Try it, for me it worked just fine. in c++/c you can also declare and initialize an array  of characters with a pointer. char * str = "Modern C++" ; use str[value] to loop through because str is now an array.

Comment: I believe the syntax without [ ] is char ** str.

Comment: `char * str = "Modern C++";` is, ironically, invalid modern C++. const is required as of C++11. https://wandbox.org/permlink/e3TA4tKbrkBOOUll (gcc) / https://wandbox.org/permlink/TFTRyB565SVyhMlb (clang)